# ESPN CricInfo maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: python, recursion, error-handling

I have imported ESPNCricInfo module shown here https://github.com/dwillis/python-espncricinfo

I am currently getting this error when running the sample code in the above link

Can anyone help with this error message? Or is it something wrong with the module

Thanks!

```
from espncricinfo.series import Series
from espncricinfo.summary import Summary
from espncricinfo.match import Match
m = Match('64148')
m.description
```

This generates the error shown below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\George\OneDrive\Documents\Python\ESPNCricInfoTest.py", line 4, in <module>
    m = Match('64148')
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\espncricinfo\match.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.json = self.get_json()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\espncricinfo\match.py", line 92, in get_json
    r = requests.get(self.json_url)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request      
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send   
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send   
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 392, in connect
    self.ssl_context = create_urllib3_context(
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 303, in create_urllib3_context
    context.options |= options
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 602, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 602, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 602, in options
    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).options.__set__(self, value)
  [Previous line repeated 490 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This should generate the output

'England [Marylebone Cricket Club] tour of Australia, Only ODI: Australia v England at Melbourne, Jan 5, 1971'

Can anyone help? Is this a generic error or is this an issue with the module itself

This error is repeated for any of the sample lines of code in the description of the module in the link above

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't look like you brought this up on the GitHub issues page for that repo, maybe that could help if you don't find answers here.

Answer (score 1):

**work around**! the module you are using has  RecursionError. so you can call espncricinfo directly and then convert the response to json.

```
import requests
match_id=64148
url= "https://www.espncricinfo.com/matches/engine/match/{0}.json".format(str(match_id))
response=requests.get(url)
j_son=response.json()
print(j_son['description'])
```

output: 'England [Marylebone Cricket Club] tour of Australia, Only ODI: Australia v England at Melbourne, Jan 5, 1971'

Comment: Thanks a lot and if I wanted to repeat the process for some of the other methods in the module such as 'Player'. How do you know what to change the url to?. Would it be something like url= "https://www.espncricinfo.com/players/engine/player/{0}.json".format(str(player_id))

Comment: for player its http://core.espnuk.org/v2/sports/cricket/athletes/277916 ` player_id=277916
url= "http://core.espnuk.org/v2/sports/cricket/athletes/{0}.json".format(str(player_id)) `

Comment: amazing thank you I've now found all of the other urls in other scripts within the module. :)

Comment: that is how we reinvent and get the workaround or would say better ways!

Comment: https://github.com/dwillis/python-espncricinfo/blob/master/espncricinfo/player.py. Last question I promise! I can quite easily get out the required output for the simpler functions where I just search for the response such as j_son['firstName'] in this player script. Is there an easy way to get the same output for some of the more complicated functions such as def _batting_fielding_averages(self): section in the link above?

Comment: is that function working from the library? actually, it's picking information from this page; https://www.espncricinfo.com/player/ajinkya-rahane-277916, I am not sure what should be math for averages.